# Don't have read permission

Tags: errors, miktex

I installed mtpro2 manually but texstudio gave the error

```
Trying to make PK font mt2mit at 720 DPI...

Running miktex-makemf.exe...

miktex-makemf: The mt2mit source file could not be found. Running ttf2pk.exe...

miktex-makepk: PK font mt2mit could not be created.

Process exited with error(s)
```

then i closed texstudio window. after opening the program again, program gave this warning:

> You don't have read permission to the file
>   C:/Users/Mert/AppData/Roaming/texstudio.

i changed the user but nothing was different.

what should i do?

(Also i tried to install another package automatically but it failed.)

Comment: Anyway, they were not correctly installed: they're vector fonts, so neither `makemf` nor `makepk` should be in action.

Comment: i completely uninstalled miktex and re installed it. now it's ok.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because a reinstallation solved the problem.

Comment: i am having a similar issue while trying in 2 ubuntu systems sudo apt-get install texstudio